# Something wrong with mirror selection?

Tags: weight-painting, mirror-modifier

relatively new to Blender. I made a model with the mirror modifier, then I followed a tutorial to rig it and everything was OK. But when I was trying to correct some weight paint I couldn't select ALL the mesh. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: if it is mirrored...you can always just select one part of the mirror - that's how the mirror works. If you apply the mirror, you can select the whole mesh.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Apply the mirror from the Object Mode. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome